# block website for a specific Mac address - lede firmware router

Tags: linux, router, mac, blocking, filtering

I am trying to block specific websites/urls in my home network only for specific users / Mac addresses, is this at all possible?
I have a Linksys WRT 1900 WRT v2 router running LEDE, a varient of OpenWRT.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using the firewall/`iptables` rules. The downside is that IP addresses might change and you would have to adopt the `iptables` configuration.

In the web GUI of Lede, navigate to

- *Network* -> *Firewall* -> "Traffic Rules"

In the *New forward rule* section give the new rule a name and verify that

- Source zone: lan
- Destination zone: wan

which is the default. Then press *Add and edit*.

Then adopt the settings as follows to your needs.

- *Source MAC address*
- *Destination address* ( the IP address of the site you want to block )
- *Action: Reject*

Finally press *Save & Apply*.

---

Another possibility would be to use an adblocker and configure it in a way that the websites you want to block are blocked by the adblocker. The downside is, that this would affect all computers on your network.
If the users can change the DNS server, they can easily configure a different DNS server and bypass this method.